# json-in-script returns "failed to load external url"

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to present some data from a Google spreadsheet on a Google Sites page using their `?alt=json-in-script` parameter when fetching the data, but all I get is "failed to load external url".

Right now I'm trying out an example from one of the Google developer guides but I still get the same result. In this case the specific error message is "25+36 - 155: failed to load external url full?alt=json-in-script&callback=listEvents" and it's returned from the code below, found at this link https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json.

```
<h3>Upcoming Google Developer Events</h3>

<div id="agenda"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function listEvents(root) {

    var feed = root.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var html = ['<ul>'];

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
      var entry = entries[i];
      var title = (entry.title.type == 'html') ? entry.title.$t : escape(entry.title.$t);
      var start = (entry['gd$when']) ? entry['gd$when'][0].startTime : ""; 

      html.push('<li>', start, ' ', title, '</li>');
    }

    html.push('</ul>');
    document.getElementById("agenda").innerHTML = html.join("");
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=listEvents">
</script>
```

Has anyone got a clue why this is happening? Is the API deprecated or what? Their guides are not that well version handled so it's hard to now if what you're reading is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sites are using a HTML Box or an Apps Script?

The example from Google developer gives the error when it is included in an HTML Box but not when included as Apps Script.

Comment: From the documentation: "Code from one HTML box can’t interact with or refer to code outside of the HTML box, including other HTML boxes." https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en

Comment: Aha, that's great help. Thanks a bunch!